# Generic Presentation Block vs Generic Structural Block

Tags: html, css

I generally think generally think of `div` as a generic structural block, and my mental designation for a generic presentational block is different. In practice I use `<div class='flair'></div>` with a media query to hide most 'flair' on small screens. My use of the flair class seems more suited to its own tag (as opposed to a class), but there's nothing in the [HTML element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) that fits this description, and the HTML spec in general seems to be [moving away from presentational tags](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/introduction.html#presentational-markup). I'm wondering if other people have considered a tag like this, or if the fact that I'm asking this question at all implies that I think of HTML elements differently than most.

For clarity, I think of a 'generic presentational block' as one that meets most of this criteria:

- is not required to understand the content of the page
- contains no text, anchors, buttons
- is not flow content

So, I have some questions:

- Do other people use a specific class to denote generic presentational blocks?
- Do you feel like an existence of such a tag would improve the HTML that most developers write? (context: I generally consider div soup to be a negative)
- How would you feel about browsers having a builtin feature that disables this tag. This feature would be a superset of tools like adblock and noscript

Comment: There are ideas floating around that would allow you to define your own tags (and by ways of hackery you could right now, making browser recognise tags using `document.createElement` in javascript), but this is a very opinion based question not suited for Stack Overflow IMHO.

Comment: This *might* be a better fit for programmers.SE. It's off-topic for here though. Oh, and one question per question in the future please.

Comment: @somethinghere I've used that feature before, but I find its more suited for creating advanced custom content, not a basic feature like this. Also yes, this question is suited for something like the W3 mailing list, but I'm on stackoverflow everyday (and on w3.org almost never) so posting here first for comfort's sake

Comment: @j08691 This is not a good fit for Programmers - it would be down voted and closed very quickly. The three questions are primarily opinion based - speculation and polls don't fit in on Programmers.

Comment: It'd likely be a good fit for a HTML subreddit, considering the voting part.

Although I'm more interested in well researched authoritative opinions, rather than popular ones.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether the question is relevant or not - I understand what you mean about "div soup," but since your flairs are semantically meaningless I think it's technically fine.

I work with a developer who uses the `<i>` tag with a `role="presentation"` attribute added. Honestly, I haven't really looked into the use of `<i>` but using `role="presentation"` for accessibility purposes may be something to look into if you haven't already? And can be used to hide presentational flairs on mobile.

https://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/#presentation

Comment: I did not know that. +1

Comment: It's probably going to take me a few hours of going through the linked page to fully understand it, but `role="presentation"` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks (albeit as its own tag rather than an attribute)

Comment: I wish I could have offered you a better explanation, but I only have basic knowledge of it as well - hope you find it useful though.